# Powershell - Capture socket and process

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying this small powershell script to look for netstat -ano output every five seconds and then filter only outgoing connections on port 80 on any IP address, plus catch the related process that opened the socket. 
I think the problem here is if there are multiple entries in the output then it cannot handle the array. What is missing here? any better way to do this?

```
while(1) {netstat -ano | ? {$_ -like "*10.10.10.10:* *:80 *"} |
  % {
  $_ -match "\d+$";
$matches | ForEach-Object {
   Get-Process -id $matches[0] | Format-List *;
   (Get-Process -id $matches[0]).WaitForExit()
}
  Start-Sleep -s 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Shay Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9833/shay-levy) wrote a function to work with `netstat` info that might help you filter down your information and outputs it in a manner that would be easier to filter on: [How to find running processes and their port number](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2011/02/10/How-to-find-running-processes-and-their-port-number.aspx)

NOTE: I know most folks probably say to post the code here in the event the page goes missing. Shay is updating this page as things change or for improvements (like adding support for IPv6 connections) so I doubt he will be taking it down anytime soon.

See [Get-NetworkStatistics](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71):

```
> Get-NetworkStatistics | where Localport -eq 8000


ComputerName  : DESKTOP-JL59SC6
Protocol      : TCP
LocalAddress  : 0.0.0.0
LocalPort     : 8000
RemoteAddress : 0.0.0.0
RemotePort    : 0
State         : LISTENING
ProcessName   : node
PID           : 11552
```